# monero blocks explorer

Tags: transaction-data

During working with the apis offered specified http://moneroblocks.info/api, I'm confused by the following 2 apis

- http://moneroblocks.info/api/get_block_header/{hash} gives me the response as
  [image: get_block_header]
- while http://moneroblocks.info/api/get_block_data/{hash} gives me the response as 
  [image]

with the same hash as **c4932f05d6d37de2799fa7e1bc58d43a12a5c61c7f317e7037a32d8fe0847bb8**, and tool empolyed to interact with the api is POSTMAN.

As seen, the response from the `get_block_header` is consistent with those  displayed on http://moneroblocks.info, but the `get_block_data` tells me that the block has no txs, and its previous hash is 0, which is obviously false.

So I wonder where is the problem, and hope someone can help me out~

Comment: It seems to be a bug in the API. Whatever parameter is passed to get_block_data, it returns the data for the genesis block. I tried passing a height instead of a hash, but that's not it.

Comment: So is there another way to explore all transactions in batch on the chain?

Comment: monerod RPC: https://getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/daemon-rpc.html (note that this documentation may be out of date in places, but it's mostly right)